# CS0117: 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a definition for 'GetXML'

Tags: asp.net, xslt

Below is the code that is causing the error. As a newbie to XSL and ASP.NET, I don't quite understand why the error is occurring...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="view.aspx.cs" Inherits="ININ.Marquee.Web.view" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.XPath" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Xsl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<html>
<head>

</head>


<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server" >
<div>
<script runat="server">

public string GetXMLAsString(XmlDocument myxml)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        myxml.WriteTo(tx);

        string str = sw.ToString();// 
        return str;
}

public static string GetHtml(string xsltPath, string xml)
{
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(xml));
 XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(stream);
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
 transform.Load(xsltPath);
 transform.Transform(document, null, writer);
 return writer.ToString();
}

public string details = string.Empty;

private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    /******** - This the START of all the Database Stuff - ********/
    // Create a String to hold the database connection string.
    // NOTE: Put in a real database connection string here or runtime won't work
    string sdwConnectionString = @"Data Source = server; user id=username; password=password; Initial Catalog = database;";

    // Create a connection
    SqlConnection sdwDBConnection = new SqlConnection(sdwConnectionString);

    // Open the connection
    sdwDBConnection.Open();

    // Create a String to hold the query.
    string query = "SELECT * from IWrkgrpQueueStats WHERE ((substring(convert(char,dIntervalStart,120),1,10) = substring(convert(char,getdate(),120),1,10)) AND (cName IN ('Password','Arbour/CMBS/Other','Incident Escalation', 'OPOM/SOS/MyAccount','PC/Outlook','Overflow')) AND (cReportGroup='*' AND cHKey3='*' AND cHKey4='*'))";


    // Create a SqlCommand object and pass the constructor the connection string and the query string.
    SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sdwDBConnection);

    // Use the above SqlCommand object to create a SqlDataReader object.
    SqlDataReader queryCommandReader = queryCommand.ExecuteReader();

    //Create a DataTable object to hold all the data returned by the query.
    DataTable duplicatedataTable = new DataTable();

    // Use the DataTable.Load(SqlDataReader) function to put the results of the query into a DataTable.
    duplicatedataTable.Load(queryCommandReader);    

    // Open the connection
    sdwDBConnection.Close();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("interactions");

    ds.Tables.Add(duplicatedataTable);

    string XML = ds.GetXML();

    details=GetHtml(Server.MapPath("~/Test.xsl"), XML); 

}
</script>   

<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr bgcolor="Silver">
<th align="center">

        <%= details %>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have reviewed both this code and the .xsl code and there doesn't appear to be any issues. Can anyone please explain what the error means and where the issue causing the error would occur? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Not all the code is provided and this leaves the reader guessing: Which is the class that contains the provided methods?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Dimitre. I have now updated the code including everything - did I need to also include the XML code? As stated, I am completely new to ASP.NET and XML and have been using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37868/Beginners-Introduction-To-XSL-Transform-Rendering as a guide to what I'm doing.

Comment: FYI, don't use New XmlTextWriter. Use XmlWriter.Create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is one of case-sensitivity.

Why don't you try:

`string XML = ds.GetXml();`

rather than

`string XML = ds.GetXML();`

Hope that helps.

Comment: BTW -- if you're using Visual Studio and Intellisense is working correctly, it can be very helpful in avoiding these kinds of problems.

Comment: "Don't code when tired" -- if only **I** could follow this advice.